# fontawsome-webfont.woff not found error in deployed Orchard CMS website

Tags: deployment, orchardcms, font-awesome

I use `Orchard CMS 1.10.1`. In the `layout.cshtml` file of current theme, I added these:

```
Style.Require("bootstrap");
Style.Require("fontawesome");
```

and the `web.config` file of `Orchard.Web` contains these:

```
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
        <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
        <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
    </staticContent>
```

In my machine there was no problem but when I deployed this on server I get these errors in browser console:

```
Get http://x.com/Themes/y/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0
GET http://x.com/Themes/y/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0 
GET http://x.com/Themes/y/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0 404 (Not Found)
```

What might cause this problem?

Comment: Perhaps the files were not deployed? Check whether the mentioned files are actually there.

Comment: I'll deploy it again, yea maybe something was missed

Answer (score 0):

You need a `<clear/>` as first element inside static handlers before first `<remove..../>` and add a ttf handler as well

Comment: Thanks for answer, In my case it didn't work, I got an error for each css file and js file that I referenced in page

Comment: Then you need to add a Web.config in your case and js directories

Comment: I already have web.config in Style and Script folders of my theme